# Google MAPS API V3 -- > How Can I count the number of Markers inside a Polygon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i think the question is clear enough  . 
I have some polygons in my Map , I have also some markers .
I want to count the amount of markers that are in every Polyogn .

Answer (score 1):

The only way of doing this without prior preparation is to iterate through your collection of markers and use point-in-polygon analysis with each polygon until you find which polygon contains that marker. Keep a running total for each polygon.

Prior preparation to make this easier would be to maintain a record of which polygon contained the marker when you added that marker. You could do that with a custom attribute of the marker —  `marker.containedBy`, for example — or the polygon (add the marker to an array attached to the polygon: something like `polygon.containsMarkers=[]`). Or even both.